# Julia - read UInt32 from UInt8 Array

Tags: arrays, julia, data-conversion

I have UInt8 data array which I got from TCPSocket.

I want to read UInt32s and UInt16s from different indices.

For example:

```
data = UInt8[0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAA, 0x00]

// Something like this:
extracted_UInt32 = data.readUInt32(1) # [1-4]
extracted_UInt16 = data.readUInt16(5) # [5-6]
```

It is exactly like Node.js's `Buffer.readUInt16LE(offset)`: https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_readint16le_offset

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [`read`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/#Base.read) the data as a given type from the buffer:

```
julia> data = IOBuffer(UInt8[0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAA, 0x00]);

julia> a = read(data, UInt32)
0x000000ff

julia> b = read(data, UInt16)
0x00aa
```

You can probably do this from the TCP socket directly without materializing as a vector of bytes.

Answer (score 5):

Also I have found [reinterpret](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.reinterpret) can be used:

```
data = UInt8[0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAA, 0x00]

a = reinterpret(UInt32, data[1:4])
b = reinterpret(UInt16, data[5:6])
```

Comment: I guess it should be `5:6`, though?

Comment: Does cropping the array to make subarrays and reinterpreting them costs more performance than reading IO Buffer? I'm curious.

Comment: Probably. In particular you will have to pay for allocations when creating the array.